# Запрос на поиск по базе

Tags: php, mysql

Есть файл search.php. К нему идут параметры

> `/search.php?name=test&num=2&param=3`

Внутри него также принимаются

```
$name = $_GET['name']; 
$num = $_GET['num']; 
$param = $_GET['param'];
```

И потом делается запрос из этих параметров в mysql. Как мне правильно сделать запрос, если я, например, напишу только

> `/search.php?num=2`

Если я так пишу, то файл вообще не работает...

Comment: "Когда я встаю утром я не могу  найти свой второй носок, где мне его искать ?"

Примерно так звучит ваш вопрос.

Comment: Ну, во-первых, лучше использовать POST, чем GET, в данном конкретном случае.  
А, во-вторых, SQL должен формироваться уже на основе количества исходных данных (если использовать что-то вроде `if($_GET['num']!=''){$num = $_GET['num']} else {$num = что-то ещё}` то при условии статичного SQL-запроса запрос не сработает из-за ошибки(не будет какого-то значения (например: `SELECT * FROM table WHERE num= param=3`)))

Comment: Вот это я и имею ввиду)
Тоесть мне придется проверять существует ли данный параметр и от этого составлять запрос?
Я просто думал вдруг можно проще..

Answer (score 2):

```
$defaults = array(
    'name' => 'anonimus',
    'num' => 1,
    'param' => 'somevalue',
);
$endarray = array_merge($defaults, $_GET);
```

Далее работаете с `$endarray`.

Comment: Я сейчас делаю так:


> http://i33.fastpic.ru/big/2012/0319/e3/adc60d5d1c55ba21acab584de384ebe3.png

Это работает. Но мне кажется что это не совсем правильно и можно как то по другому сделать...

Comment: И вдруг - бах! - надо ввести еще один параметр. Как будет выглядеть код в этом случае? =)

Comment: Я про этоже. Кто как делает в таких ситуациях?

Comment: Я же в ответе написал пример. О_о  
Если надо добавить еще один параметр для запроса, он добавляется в массив $defaults.

Answer (score 0):

Слишком мало информации, нужен исходник запроса к базе. 
Как вариант запрос не шлется из-за IF условия на наличие значений переменных или на существование переменных - но это пальцем в небо, нужен исходник.

Comment: Да я даже не про запрос говорю, я про обращение к файлу php

Comment: Запрос оформлен правильно, как пример:

поиск-php-mysql?страница=1&focusedAnswerId=91167

Comment: В любом случае нужен исходник дабы узнать как фильтруются переменные, есть ли условия, как потом они складываются в запрос и т.д.

Comment: Это понятно, а как обратиться к странице если я ищу только по одному параметру?

Comment: пффф, как всё сложно.

"А как мне купить в аптеке хлеба ?"

Вот так же и со скриптами, если они не предоставляют такой функционал - то никак (ну можно дописать конечно скрипт, но это уже юудет второй скрипт :) )

Comment: ...или завести в аптеку хлеб и картошку))))

В любом случае надо спрашивать у покупателя, что он желает, если ему нужно только num=2, то остальные товары в аптеке не класть в корзину.

Answer (score 0):

если нужно чтоб скрипт работал только по одному параметру при не заданных других (я правильно понял?), то внутри скрипта проверяется входящие параметры isset'ом, и если не задан - задается значение по умолчанию (логика может быть и сложнее).
Пример:

```
$name = "anonymous";
if(isset($_GET['name']))
$name = $_GET['name'];

$param = 0;
if(isset($_GET['param ']))
$param = $_GET['param '];
else if($name == "admin" )
$param = 777;//например
```

О безопасности не забываем! Проверяем все реквесты, чтобы не было инъекций!